# Global variable or switch statement to enable and disable comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement, global-variables, comments

I am looking for a global variable or a switch statement at the beginning of the code to enable or disable specific comments.
For example, I want to decide at the beginning of my script whether to save my plots or not:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(1, 91), scores_df["MaeCvMean"])
ax.fill_between(np.arange(1, 91), scores_df["MaeCvMean"] + scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.975)*scores_df["MaeCvStd"],
                scores_df["MaeCvMean"] - scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.975)*scores_df["MaeCvStd"], color="C0", alpha=0.15)
ax.set(xlabel="Minute", ylabel="Mae")
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 100, step=10))
plt.legend(["Mae", "95% CI"], loc="upper left", fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.savefig("../Figures/cv_mae_ann.pdf", format="pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

In this example, I want to control in the preamble whether to switch off the plt.savefig command.
I could imagine a switch statement like this:

```
COMMENTING = 0  # 0 to disable comments and 1 to enable comments
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

```
DEBUG = True #flag to control comments

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(1, 91), scores_df["MaeCvMean"])
ax.fill_between(np.arange(1, 91), scores_df["MaeCvMean"] + scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.975)*scores_df["MaeCvStd"],
                scores_df["MaeCvMean"] - scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.975)*scores_df["MaeCvStd"], color="C0", alpha=0.15)
ax.set(xlabel="Minute", ylabel="Mae")
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 100, step=10))
plt.legend(["Mae", "95% CI"], loc="upper left", fancybox=True, shadow=True)
if DEBUG: #<-- add here
    plt.savefig("../Figures/cv_mae_ann.pdf", format="pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```